# How to duplicate the row of the previous month, when it's missing in the next month?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with the following data set:

```
Calendar Year/Month ID  Money spent Money spent_pm
       01/07/2021   1       10          null
       01/08/2021   1       20          10
       01/09/2021   1       15          20
       01/07/2021   2       12          null
       01/08/2021   2       10         12
       01/07/2021   3       17         null
       01/07/2021   4       10         null
       01/08/2021   4       21         10
       01/09/2021   4       12         21
```

The problem with the data is that the total of Money spent_pm in my reports doesn't add up. This is because, for example, the row of 01/08/2021 of ID 2 is missing in the source data when the money spent in that month is 0. I want to add a row when this is happening, such that the data frame would look like this:

```
Calendar Year/Month ID  Money spent Money spent_pm
       01/07/2021   1       10          null
       01/08/2021   1       20          10
       01/09/2021   1       15          20
       01/07/2021   2       12          null
       01/08/2021   2       10         12
       01/09/2021   2       null       10
       01/07/2021   3       17         null
       01/08/2021   3       null       17
       01/07/2021   4       10         null
       01/08/2021   4       21         10
       01/09/2021   4       12         21
```

Here, as you can see, a row is added for ID numbers 2 and 3 because otherwise, their money spent_pm would be missing in the data. The row only needs to be posted if the Money spent in the previous month is not equal to null. Can you please help me with how I can produce this with Python code?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why `Money spent_pm` of ID 1 is `null, 10, 15` instead of `null, 10, 20`? Also, where is your code? At least create a minimal code for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake on my side... I just created some dummy data for this question. It should be null, 10, 20.

This is the code I'm using for creating the Money spent_pm column:
    df = df.sort_values(["ID", "Calendar Year/Month"])
    df["Money spent_pm"] = df.groupby("ID")["Money spent"].shift()